# Вернуть BITMAP из unmanaget dll

Tags: c#, bitmap

Пробовал вернуть HBITMAP из unmanaged dll на c++, но его C# не хочет переваривать, описал его как возвращаемый IntPtr, пишет о невозможности преобразования из IntPtr в Bitmap, код примерно следующий:

```
   IntPtr ptr = function_from_c();
   Bitmap bmp = ptr as Bitmap;
```

как правильно это все организовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте статический метод  [Image.FromHbitmap(IntPtr hbitmap)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromhbitmap?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Image_FromHbitmap_System_IntPtr_).